# Using PHP/PDO to set a NULL as value when UPDATE by array

Tags: php, sql, pdo

*i am executing SQL statement like this with PDO.*

```
$SQL_stmt = "UPDATE `home_slides` SET main_title=?,sub_title=?,slide_type=?,photo=?,video_small=?,video_large=? WHERE `id`=1"
$DBH_stmt = $PDOcon->prepare($SQL_stmt);
$DBH_stmt->execute($_POSTData_array);
```

*and $_POSTData_array is like this*

```
Array ( 
    [0] => PIC_Testings 
    [1] => City 
    [2] => pic 
    [3] => 88c85c6670ac164f0a97c85ce5d25211.jpg 
    [4] => null 
    [5] => null
)
```

the problem is i can't get the null as null in db, its update as blank.
any help???

**UPDATE !**

as per comment by Álvaro González i tried var_dump().

> var_dump() is much better. I need to insist: how do you know that
>   you're getting NULL values upon insertion? – Álvaro González

```
// result of var_dump($_POSTData_array);
array(6) {
  [0] => string(12) "PIC Testings"
  [1] => string(5) "Citys"
  [2] => string(3) "pic"
  [3] => string(36) "88c85c6670ac164f0a97c85ce5d25211.jpg"
  [4] => string(0) ''
  [5] => string(0) ''
}
```

so actually there was no NULL set in the $_POSTData_array.
guess var_dump() way much more batter then print_r() to verifying data.

Comment: Does your column allow null values? Your code should work.

Comment: yes it dose, and i have tried in PHPmyadmin.

Comment: If that's the output of `print_r()`, then your value does not contain `null` but `'null'` (a string with the word null). Of course that doesn't explain blanks but...

Comment: @Álvaro-gonzález  that is the print_r(),
and i have tested both ways too.
with 'null' => field value come null as text.
with null => field value come black.

Comment: Alright... How are you verifying the database insertion? My point is that `print_r()` is not a good diagnostic tool.

Comment: print_r() is what i am using now.. any suggestion of good tool for verifying

Comment: I agree with the others. If the value in the input_parameters array is truly null and not the word 'null', the affected fields should be null after the UPDATE. I just confirmed this in MySQL.

Comment: `var_dump()` is much better. I need to insist: how do you know that you're getting NULL values upon insertion?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález u were right about data not been set as NULL. chk question i have update with new information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a Solution.

**Solution 1**
while creating the array elements use array_push.

```
$_POSTData_array= []
if (empty($_POST[$FieldName])) {
   // $_POSTData_array[] .= `null`;   // previous method
   array_push($_POSTedData, null);    // new method
} else {
   array_push($_POSTedData, $_POST[$FieldName]);
}
```

**Solution 2**
using array_map to set Null to blank elements after creating the array before executing PDO statement.

```
$_POSTedData_array = array_map(function($value) {
                        return $value === "" ? NULL : $value;
                     }, $_POSTedData_array);
```

**new result of var_dump($_POSTData_array); for both solutions**

```
array(6) {
  [0] => string(12) "PIC Testings"
  [1] => string(5) "Citys"
  [2] => string(3) "pic"
  [3] => string(36) "88c85c6670ac164f0a97c85ce5d25211.jpg"
  [4] => NULL
  [5] => NULL
}
```

***Thanks for all the help everyone.***

*and to those who '**downvote**' my question, guess what! there is a solution after all.*